# Iterate and compare Java List

Tags: java, list, liferay

My query from the `MasterList` Table fetches following records:

```
id   listName            listValue
1   Type of Repository  Animal Specimen
2   Type of Repository  Human Specimen
3   Type of Repository  Environmental Specimen
4   Type of Repository  Microorganism Culture Collection
5   Type of Repository  Vegetal Specimen
6   Type of Repository  Other
```

Each record/row is an object and is stored as list of objects in the following list

```
List<MasterList> typeOfRepositoryMasterList
```

Also each object has corresponding `getter` methods for columns available like `obj.getListValue();`

Then from other query to `biobankList` Table I have following records:

```
biobankId listName           listValue
1       Type of Repository  Animal Specimen
1       Type of Repository  Human Specimen
1       Type of Repository  Microorganism Culture Collection
1       Type of Repository  Vegetal Specimen
```

Similarly these records are also available as list of objects as

```
List<biobankList> typeOfRepositoryBiobankList
```

and each object here also has corresponding `getter` methods.

What I want to do is, for all the `listValue` in the first record set, if there is the same `listValue` in the second record set, add that to the new list say `selectedList`. The two `listValue`s which are not present in the second record set should be added to the `availableList`.  The picture might explain better.[image]

```
for(MasterList attributeMaster: typeOfRepositoryMasterList){
        boolean selected = false;
        for(biobankList attribute: typeOfRepositoryBiobankList){
            if(attributeMaster.getListValue().equals(attribute.getListValue())){
                System.out.println("equal");
                selected = true;
                selectedList.add(new KeyValuePair(
                        attribute.getListName()+"_"+attribute.getListValue(), attribute.getListValue()));
                break;
            }
            if(!selected){
                System.out.println("not equal");
                availableList.add(new KeyValuePair(
                            attributeMaster.getListName()+"_"+attributeMaster.getListValue(), attributeMaster.getListValue()));

            }
        }


    }
```

The query is working fine but this nested for loop code is clearly not working as it adds the same values multiple times.

**Edit:** I tried adding the `boolean` but still the problem persists. I am getting correct values in the selectedList but apparently the availableList contains duplicate values. Here is the screenshot.[image]

Comment: add !list.contains(Object o) to your if

Comment: I tried that as well but it still does not work as I get repeated values in the availableList.

Comment: have a look at my answer I think you have problem with availableList don't you?

Comment: yes I have the problem with the availableList, selectedList displays the correct values. I tried to do your way but still does not work.

Comment: Can you provide what you get from running that code?

Comment: @AliMotevallian: Please check the updated screen shot.

Comment: @SASM: You are still making a mistake. You should check the boolean OUTSIDE the second loop. The whole problem is that you are checking it INSIDE the inner loop. Please look into my code I have taken it out of the inner loop. The logic is I allow the inner loop to find a match. If it is finished and could not find a match (after the second loop is finished) then I add it to availableList. I have tested that code and it works fine.

Comment: @AliMotevallian: Oops did not realize that. Seems like it solved the problem. Let me check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60238/discussion-between-ali-motevallian-and-sasm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the else statement. Each time the inner loop is called and the there is no match (attribute and attributeMaster have different listValue) your code will add that listValue to availableList.

You have to change your logic in this way:

Define a boolean outside the second loop and set it to false. Whenever a match found (just before the `break;`) line set it to true.

Outside the 2nd loop check if that boolean is true (means that the current 'attributeMaster' has been matched) do not add it to the availableList. Here is the correct code:

```
for(MasterList attributeMaster: typeOfRepositoryMasterList){
    boolean found = false;
    for(biobankList attribute: typeOfRepositoryBiobankList){
        if(attributeMaster.getListValue().equals(attribute.getListValue())){
            System.out.println("equal");
            selectedList.add(new KeyValuePair(attribute.getListName()+"_"+attribute.getListValue(), attribute.getListValue()));
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("not equal");
        availableList.add(new KeyValuePair(attributeMaster.getListName()+"_"+attributeMaster.getListValue(),attributeMaster.getListValue()));

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to rethink the whole approach to solve the problem.

I would create two Sets, one for each type:

```
Set<String> typeOfRepositoryMasterList
Set<String> typeOfRepositoryBiobankList
```

After that you can create your two desired sets easily by using:

```
//Selected list is an intersection of the two sets
selectedList = new HashSet<String>(typeOfRepositoryMasterList);
selectedList.retainAll(typeOfRepositoryBiobankList);

//Available list can be constructed in a similar fashion
availableList = new HashSet<String>(typeOfRepositoryMasterList);
availableList.addAll(typeOfRepositoryBiobankList);
availableList.removeAll(selectedList);
```